# Htaccess rules. redirecting from an android version to the pc version

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect from the android version to the pc version, with this rule:

```
http://example.com/android/categories



     RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Android [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^categories$ [NC]
RewriteRule categories$ /categories [L,R,QSA]
```

problem is that the android version goes inside the rewrite condition, even when i tell it not to go if the user agent is either iphone and android..

Why does the android version read that rule?

And in this example:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule hot$ /hot-apps  [L,R,QSA]
RewriteRule android/news$ /news  [L,R,QSA]
```

The first rewrite rule works..while the next one doesnt..

I also did this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule iphone/contact$ /contact [L,R,QSA]
```

This doesnt work too:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/android/ [NC]
RewriteRule news$ /news  [L,R,QSA]
```

But still doesnt work properly?

Comment: You posted too many questions within one and I'm really confused. Can you please tell me exactly what's the url that you would like to redirect and to where you would like to redirect it? One by one and start with the first code. I really would love to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a direct PC equivalent for all the Android / iPhone / mobile URL's e.g.

```
http://example.com/android/categories   <->   http://example.com/categories
http://example.com/android/news         <->   http://example.com/news
http://example.com/iphone/contact       <->   http://example.com/contact
```

Then you could use a single rule along the following lines:

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}     !(droid|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|mobile|palmos|webos)  [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}         ^/(android|iphone)/ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(android|iphone)/(.*)  /$1 [L,R]
```